# Scrape Google Maps results Website URL selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to search with python via Google Maps and I want to get the URL from the results.

Following steps I approach:

1. open google
2. Accept cookies
3. Search for random thing (in this example "pediatrician in Aargau")
4. switch to google maps

This is where I get the error, as I am trying to wait for the results to load, but I always get a timeout. I can see in the window that opens, that the results are fully loaded.

Is there anything wrong with my code? I would like to extract the website URL of the results.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Start the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open google.de and accept cookies
driver.get("https://www.google.de/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#L2AGLb > div"))).click()

# Search for "Kinderarzt Kanton Aargau"
search_box = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
search_box.send_keys("Kinderarzt Kanton Aargau")
search_box.submit()

# Switch to Maps tab
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(), 'Maps')]"))).click()

# Wait for links and extract
results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label^='Results for'] > div > div > a")))
for result in results:
    link = result.get_attribute("href")
    print(link)


# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

PS: I have tried to increase the time for the webdriver, but that won't help. I think it can not find the object and there must be another way to identify the objects.

Comment: Which element is `(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#L2AGLb > div")`

Comment: that is the Cookies popup , that comes up, when i open google. It clicks the button to accept all cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can skip several steps by just building the URL for google maps with the desired search string. Second, your "Wait for results to load" locator was not on my page. My guess is that the class you are using is changing regularly. I used a different CSS selector and found it just fine.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Start the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Declare string to search for and encode it
search_string = "Kinderarzt Kanton Aargau"
partial_url = search_string.replace(" ", "+")

# Open google.de and accept cookies
driver.get(f"https://www.google.de/maps/search/{partial_url}/")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 25)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#L2AGLb > div"))).click()

# Wait for links and extract
results = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[aria-label^='Results for'] > div > div > a")))
for result in results:
    link = result.get_attribute("href")
    print(link)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

The result is

```
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Dr.+med.+Helena+Gerritsma+Schirlo/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x47903be8d0d4a09d:0xc97d85a6fa076207!8m2!3d47.3906733!4d8.0443884!16s%2Fg%2F1tghc1gd!19sChIJnaDU0Og7kEcRB2IH-qaFfck?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Kinderarztpraxis+Dr.+med.+Armin+B%C3%BChler+%26+Thomas+Justen/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x479069d7b30c674b:0xd04693e64cbc42b0!8m2!3d47.5804824!4d8.2163541!16s%2Fg%2F1ptw0srs4!19sChIJS2cMs9dpkEcRsEK8TOaTRtA?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Kinderarztpraxis+Lenzburg/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x4790160e650976b1:0x5352d33510a53d99!8m2!3d47.3855278!4d8.1753395!16s%2Fg%2F11hz17jwcy!19sChIJsXYJZQ4WkEcRmT2lEDXTUlM?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Kinderarzthaus+-+Kinderarztpraxis/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x47903bf002633251:0xf029086640b016ee!8m2!3d47.391928!4d8.051698!16s%2Fg%2F11cfdn2j8!19sChIJUTJjAvA7kEcR7hawQGYIKfA?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Dr.+med.+Nils+Hammerich/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x4790160e650976b1:0x7116ed2cc14996ea!8m2!3d47.3856086!4d8.1753854!16s%2Fg%2F1tl0w7qv!19sChIJsXYJZQ4WkEcR6pZJwSztFnE?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Kinderarzt+Berikon/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x47900e152314a493:0x72ca7fe58b7b3a5f!8m2!3d47.3612625!4d8.3674472!16s%2Fg%2F11c311g_px!19sChIJk6QUIxUOkEcRXzp7i-V_ynI?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Dr.+med.+Hana+Balent+Ilitsch/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x4790697f95fe3a73:0xaff715a22ab56e78!8m2!3d47.5883105!4d8.2882387!16s%2Fg%2F11hyjwg_32!19sChIJczr-lX9pkEcReG61KqIV968?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Dr.+med.+Belzer+Heierling+Tanja/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x47906d2a4e9698fd:0x6865ac23234b8dc9!8m2!3d47.4637622!4d8.3284463!16s%2Fg%2F1tksm8d9!19sChIJ_ZiWTiptkEcRyY1LIyOsZWg?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Praxis+f%C3%BCr+Kinder-+und+Jugendmedizin+Dr.+Dirk+Bock/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x47906b5c9071d861:0x516c763f7642c9ff!8m2!3d47.4731839!4d8.1959905!16s%2Fg%2F11mpc9wm91!19sChIJYdhxkFxrkEcR_8lCdj92bFE?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Alleviamed+Kinderarztpraxis+Meisterschwanden/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x4790193bdf03b5f1:0xfef98e265772814a!8m2!3d47.2956342!4d8.2279202!16s%2Fg%2F11gr2z_z2f!19sChIJ8bUD3zsZkEcRSoFyVyaO-f4?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
https://www.google.de/maps/place/Kinderarztpraxis+Suhrepark+AG/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x47903c69ae471281:0xcb34880030319dd7!8m2!3d47.3727496!4d8.0809937!16s%2Fg%2F1v3kl_4v!19sChIJgRJHrmk8kEcR150xMACINMs?authuser=0&hl=en&rclk=1
```

Comment: I cant seem to figure it out, if i use your code I am getting the accept cookies messages and it looks a bit different and it does not click the accept button, or at least it doesnt work.
If I combine mine and your code (my google search + switch to maps + your CSS Selector), i am still getting a timeout exception.
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
.....
     25     link = result.get_attribute("href")

PS: I am using a macbook if that has to be considered.

Comment: I can visibly see that the results are loaded , i see the list view on the left with the results and on the right the google-map from google maps
I updated the code in the original post at the top, so you can see what i am using right now

Comment: I don't get the accept cookies popup so I didn't change that code and locator. Maybe you need to based on what you're seeing? I tested my code so I know it's working other the the cookies accept prompt which I don't get. I would suggest you use only my code and update the cookies accept locator to whatever you are seeing. The rest should work.